# how to change winetricks default wineprefix directory

Tags: directory, default, winetricks

I want to modify wineprefix installed with playonlinux using Winetricks.

Answer (score 7):

You could stick

```
export WINEPREFIX=/home/$USER/.playonlinux/path/to/prefix/
```

in `~/.bashrc` (and then run `source ~/.bashrc` to load it the first time if you're already in a terminal)

Or just prefix your `winetricks`  commands like:

```
WINEPREFIX=/home/$USER/.playonlinux/path/to/prefix/ winetricks blah blah blah
```

---

I don't use POL but I have in the past and I rather thought there was a button or menu item that let you run various `winetricks` things without having to run it manually. I'm probably wrong but give it a look.